# connect by level does not adjust with the change of the field in each row

Tags: sql, oracle

Let me start my question by setting up my scenario.

I have a test2 table which contains only 2 fields: productid and productlife, I would like to explicitly list all the years along with the products

[image: ![enter image description here]

for example,

With product A, I would like to list

```
Y15|Y16|Y17|Y18|Y19, A
```

and for product B, using the same rule, I should get

```
Y18|Y19, B
```

My sql does not produce the result I am looking for:

```
SELECT
  (
  SELECT listagg("Year",'|') within GROUP (
  ORDER BY "Year") "Prefix"
  FROM
    (
    SELECT 'Y'
      ||(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'yy')-LEVEL) "Year"
    FROM dual
      CONNECT BY level<=r.productlife
    )
  ) "Prefix", productid
FROM TEST2 r
```

How should it be corrected? I would think the field productlife in each record will control the level in the statement but it does not seem to do so..

Please advise.

Below is the script to create my example for your convenience.

```
CREATE TABLE "TEST2" 
(   productid VARCHAR2(20 BYTE), 
    productlife NUMBER
   )  ;
Insert into TEST2 (productid,productlife) values ('A',5);
Insert into TEST2 (productid,productlife) values ('B',2);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can you explain why for 5 you want 5 years, and for 1 you want 2 years?

Comment: @gsalem: My apologies.. typo, should be 2 for 2 years.. let me adjust that

Comment: your query return the correct answer, after your edit, no? At least I get the answer you want, with your query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it doesn't absolutely have to use `connect by`, another approach might be to write it explicitly as a function:

```
with
    function list_years(n number) return varchar2 as
        end_year   date := trunc(sysdate,'YYYY');
        start_year date := add_months(end_year, (n*-12));
        y date;
        years_list varchar(200);
    begin
        for i in reverse 1..n loop
            y := add_months(sysdate, -12 * i);
            years_list := years_list || to_char(y,'"Y"YY"|"');
        end loop;

        return rtrim(years_list,'|');
    end list_years;
select productid
     , productlife
     , list_years(productlife) as prefix
from   test2
/
```

[DBFiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f60005480ccb4cc43a79340ed4410015)

Comment: Connect by does not have to be used, I just was not smart enough to use function as I am still rookie in Oracle. Your solution is elegant. I appreciate you sharing your knowledge.

Answer (score 2):

This query will do it, but I feel like there must be a better way:

```sql
SELECT t.productid, s.yr
FROM test2 t
INNER JOIN (SELECT ROWNUM RN, TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY')-ROWNUM+1 YR
            FROM dual d
            CONNECT BY level <= (SELECT max(productlife)
                                 FROM test2)) s ON t.productlife >= s.rn
ORDER BY t.productid, s.yr;
```

Here is a SQLFiddle for you: [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/b6f8f9/16/0)

Comment: Thanks @Del. Your solution seems to magically work. Question: why do you need to join t.productlife >= s.rn? Might elaborating it a little bit? I am a little bit fuzzy about the mechanism behind it.

Comment: @user1205746 - Sorry for the delay.  Haven't been on in a few days.  The subquery creates a view which has rows for each year back to the longest product life in your catalog.  The >= in the join ensures that you are only grabbing the rows which are valid for the current product.  So, if your max product life is 5, the subquery will have [[1, 20][2, 19][3, 18][4, 17][5, 16]].  If the current product only has a life of two years, it will only grab the first two rows since those are the only two where the product life is greater than or equal to the rownum.